# ASP.NET image retrieval from folder

Tags: asp.net, image, imageurl

I am trying to retrieve images in ASP.NET page from a folder. The images are in JPEG format and tagged with an ID, e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc. I retrieve these IDs from the web app programmatically and save the info in a label.

In the ASP.NET source page I tried to use,

```
Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<% "Figures/" & Me.lblid.Text & ".jpg"%>"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is Javascript/jQuery allowed in your project?

Comment: Yes, Javascript can be used. However the ID of images are populated into ASP.NET variables and this may require some variables passing JS/ASP.NET and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is not capable of attaching to other controls in this fashion on the web side of the page. In order to achieve this you would need to do this in the code behind, at some point after the other piece has been completed. I'm assuming you're using some sort of data bind to accomplish this. One simple way to do this would be to use the Page_PreRender event to assign any specific images:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)

    Me.Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Figures/" & lblid.Text & ".jpg"

End Sub
```

*Note: Added ~ in url for dynamic parsing of the url as recommended by @Amiram Korach*

Comment: `"/Figures/"` will always be translated by the browser to `http://[host]/Figures` which is not necessarily right, for example if your site is under `http://[host]/[sitename]/`. You have to use the "~" sign.

Comment: @AmiramKorach: Understandably, but my understanding of the question is that the path itself is not OP's problem, injecting the id from the label is the confusion point. Other answers appear to address that issue but don't take into account the concept that the `lblid.Text` field specified in the html source will be valid only on `Page_Load`. Any subsequent data bindings or events will change that value and result (most likely) in a blank ImageUrl.

Comment: Yes. Doing this in prerender sounds better.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Your solution worked. In addition, I added the "~" sign, as suggested by AmiramKorach. Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "=" in the start of the expression and to use "~" if "Figures" is in the root folder.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
     ImageUrl="<%= "~/Figures/" & Me.lblid.Text & ".jpg" %>" />
```